# The smallest valid alpha value in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Some of my plots have several million lines. I dynamically adjust the `alpha` value, by the number of lines, so that the outliers more or less disappear, while the most prominent features appear clear. But for some `alpha`'s, the lines just disappear.

What is the smallest valid `alpha` value for line plots in in matplotlib? And why is there a lower limit?

Comment: I suppose the discretization limit is 8 bit, so the smallest value would be 1/256.

Comment: Just tested it and this seems to be right. Setting the alpha value to 1.0/255 and all the lines are there. Setting it to 1.0/256, and they are all gone. So, @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, I'll approve your answer, if you make one!

Comment: Feel free to post your finding as answer yourself, since I didn't test this, nor did I look into the source code to verify.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As @ImportanceOfBeingErnest suggested in the comments, the lower limit seems to be `1/255`.

I did not have time to go though the source code and all, but I did test it, and assume what happens is, that the input `alpha` value needs to be represented as an int between 0 and 255:

```
int(alpha*255)
```

When the input `alpha` value is smaller than `1/255`, e.g. `1/256`, it is therefore represented by a `0`, and the plot lines disappear. Whereas when the `alpha` is `1/255` (or slightly larger), it is converted to `1`, and the plot lines can be seen.

Comment: I think this is no longer (?) true, at least in my version and with my backend (in case that is of relevance). Giving details [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74287238/).

Answer (score 2):

My guess would also have been `1./255` such that the maximum 8-bit RGB color multiplied with alpha still makes a non-zero contribution to the image. However, that would also only allow to draw lines with fully saturated colors, and in reality it is not true.

Changing the relevant value in

```
for i in range(1000):
    plt.plot((0, 100), (0, 100), alpha = 1/510, color = "g")
```

I found that the limit is actually 510 (i.e., the minimum alpha is `1./510`). This holds true also for non-saturated colors (e.g., "wheat"), so reality is obviously still more complicated than the naive assumption described above.
My matplotlib version is `3.4.2`.

I haven't investigated this further -- for very large numbers of overlaid images one would have to come up with a different approach anyway. There is a related [ticket on github](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/2287) that suggests using `mplcairo`. Another option would be to export the output images as `numpy` arrays so that one can manually add and normalize them.

Comment: The minimum does seem to be 1/510, thanks for this!

Answer (score -2):

There's no lower limit; the lines just appear to be invisible for very small alpha values.

If you draw one line with alpha=0.01 the difference in color is too small for your screen / eyes to discern. If you draw 100 lines with a=0.01 on top of each other, you will see them.

As for your problem, you can just add a small number to the alpha value of each draw call so that lines that would otherwise have alpha < 0.1 still appear.